# How to install pip for python3.6 when you have python3.6 and python3.7 installed on your machine?

Tags: python, pip, zlib

I have Ubuntu 19.04. It has python2.7 and python3.7 which are working perfectly fine. Although for a school project I need to install python3.6.8 which I did by the makefile process. Unfortunately for some reason pip is not installed. (Or may be thats how its supposed to be, tbh I don't know. This is my first time installing python from source)

Anyways, I need to install some modules for python3.6.8 and if I do pip3 install SomeModule, it goes to the python3.7 version and says the module is already installed (in this case numpy). So I tried doing

```
python3.6 -m pip install numpy
```

to which I get

```
/usr/local/bin/python3.6: No module named pip
```

I've tried searching for answers but couldn't find any that meet my requirements. What is the possible solution to this?

I've already tried installing get-pip.py which didn't work either. It gives me a zlib not found error, even though I have zlib installed.

The zlib error while tring to run get-pip.py after downloading it using curl:

```
python3.6 get-pip.py

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "get-pip.py", line 21492, in <module>
    main()
  File "get-pip.py", line 197, in main
    bootstrap(tmpdir=tmpdir)
  File "get-pip.py", line 82, in bootstrap
    import pip._internal
zipimport.ZipImportError: can't decompress data; zlib not available
```

What's Expected : Easy installing of python modules after installing pip
What's Happening : No module named pip error

**TLDR;
How to install pip for 3.6 when you have both 3.6 and 3.7 installed**

Comment: instead of doing this manually, install python 3.6 from the deadsnakes PPA: https://launchpad.net/~deadsnakes/+archive/ubuntu/ppa. then get-pip should work, as well as `python3.6 -m ensurepip`

Comment: Hey! Thank you for your reply. I'm a noob in this. Can you please elaborate?